# how I show average of ratings

Tags: flutter

I am making an app in flutter where you can let a rating to a page , this is some of the code that I use but I am interested how can I show the average.

```
Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(flex: 4, child: Text("Stars given: ")),
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 6,
                            child: DropdownButton<int>(
                                value: rating,
                                items: List<DropdownMenuItem<int>>.generate(
                                    5,
                                    (index) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                                          value: index + 1,
                                          child: _buildRatingStars(index + 1),
                                        )),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  newState(() => rating = value);
                                }))
                      ],
                    ),

Text _buildRatingStars(int rating) {
  String stars = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
    stars += '⭐ ';
  }
  stars.trim();
  return Text(stars);
}
 _buildRatingStars(snapshot
                                                  .data
                                                  .documents[index]
                                                  .data["rating"]),
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal is to perform the average logic on the server side when we have a considerable sum of data so as not to affect the performance of the application.

In your case, you should store in a variable the sum of all the ratings in your array and then divide the result by the number of ratings. So you will get your average.

**Example**

```
int sumRating = 0;
List<int> listRating = [1,4,2,5,2,1];

for (var i = 0; i < listRating; i++) {
  sumRating += listRating[i];
}

var average = (sumRating / listRating.length); // This is average
```